# Can LaTeX be a Replacement for Scratch Paper?

Tags: tex-general

I am a university student and I want to begin using LaTeX for math/physics homework. What I want to do is be able to solve problems directly in LaTeX instead of solving them on paper and then typing them afterwards. However, I'm not sure if this is viable as I am much slower typing in LaTeX (I just started learning) compared to handwriting. By the way, I am currently using emacs with AucTeX and Yasnippets.

I'd imagine that it is not since it can be difficult to keep track of complex equations in one's head. Also, looking at LaTeX code is not as easy as just looking at handwritten equations. And having to compile over and over while viewing a pdf can become cumbersome and distracting. However, most answers on this quora post suggest that it is possible. https://www.quora.com/If-youre-proficient-enough-with-LaTeX-then-can-you-effectively-use-your-TeX-editor-as-scratch-paper-for-solving-math-problems. In fact they say it is even more efficient. But, don't you lost the functionality of being able to draw diagrams quickly and write your thoughts in the margin?

If one becomes proficient enough using LaTeX, can it be a replacement for scratch paper? Does anyone have any experience with this, and if so, what was your setup and would you recommend an undergrad to do the same?

Comment: My experience is that, on the long run, it is advantageous to type notes in LaTeX. Of course it takes some time to get familiar with it, but in the end it pays off.

Comment: I'm not sure this has an answer. It's more or less like asking if you can use a typewriter to take down lecture notes. You can or can not depending on your typing  proficiency. I am reasonably proficient at tex and incompetent at typing so I wouldn't even try. (and TeX wasn't invented when I was an undergraduate so I didn't try at the time either)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the problem is simple where you have the solution already in mind, you can type it immediately with LaTeX. Transforming an expression or an equation step by step is also easy by copying the line, modifying it, copying, modifying ... **However** if it is a harder problem, then trying various methods and ideas on paper seems to be much faster than getting distracting by typesetting. Solving a problem and typesetting the solution are two different things that probably shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: It depends on your field of study.  If you are a "proper" math field, like mathematics or physics, I would suggest to use paper for work, but LaTeX for things that you think may stay with you for some time.  I know at least one person, who managed to use TeX even for analytic calculations in theoretical physics, but that is more of an anecdotal example -- for most people paper provides important feedback for thinking.  Also, as a hint -- in AuxTeX there exists "preview mode (C-c c-p c-p), which renders formulas inside the current window.

Comment: This seems very opinion based, but FWIW, I used to do my maths homework in LaTeX and I loved the ability to copy and paste from the line above and manipulate quite quickly, but it could take a while to input the control sequences and I'm not sure whether it worked out faster overall, but I had fun doing it and I loved the fact I could share my work with others and keep backups and stuff.

Comment: I also found that having to think about layout and presentation quite genuinely improved my understanding of mathematical notation and I had to really think about the logic of my mathematics more than I think I would have done scribbling the solution down by hand. It was also much less tedious adding words and sentences because I could type out something like `where $l$ is the line from the point $(1, 2)$ to the point $(7, 11)$` much more quickly than I could write it. But equally, as has been observed, the typesetting is probably a distraction.

Comment: For what it's worth, Donald Knuth the inventor of TeX and of its syntax for mathematics, uses pen and paper for everything,  only typing things in at the very end. But then again, this is also how he writes code (most of TeX was written first on stacks of yellow writing pads, then typed into a computer at the very end), so he is not exactly typical.

Comment: I use a mixture, doing the original equations on paper then typing them up.  This not only increases the readability, it makes it easier to check for errors.